# Textbox calculation appears only after navigating through other records in access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I have a form that is linked to a table in Access. I have an additional field which displays the sum of a few fields in the table. This field on the form is not connected to the table. I have the sum displayed on the form but what I noticed is that the sum does not appear until I move away and navigate to another record and come back to the original record. I don't see the addition as soon as I enter values in the respective fields.

Can someone help with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to add some code to the `After Update` events of the controls for the fields used in the sum. That code can call the `.Refresh` method of the control that performs the calculation and update the total.

### Edit

Another possibility is that there could be ambiguity between *control* values and *field* values if they have the same name. In Design View for a report if you drag a field from the "Field List" and drop it into a report then Access creates a report control with the same name as the field. This can confuse matters later because if any expressions refer to `=[SomeColumn]` it's not clear whether that refers to the field or the control. Often simply renaming the controls to something like `txtSomeColumn` can help if a report is acting strangely.

Comment: It was alright some time back. i don't know why this is happening now. I thought it had something to do with the afterupdate too. But after update of which field? Because there are many fields on the form which are being updated? I can't code into afterupdate event of all of them

Comment: @amirshadaab You don't necessarily have to add `After Update` code for every field on the form, just for every field *involved in the sum*. If the sum happens to be based on 20 fields then you have to tweak the `After Update` code for each one (if you want the sum to be updated, that is...).

Comment: That is exactly what I was saying. I have a lot of fields that need to be added and this sounds tedious :(